# Parallelogram menu bar with -webkit-transform causes multiple bugs

Tags: css

Recently, I created a navigation bar and transformed the menu items into a parallelogram using `-webkit-transform:skew(-30deg);` and the [tweaks of the community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996376/css-base64-background-image-transforms-after-using-webkit-transform/).

Now, I tried fixing the dropdown menus with the CSS class `.submenu`. 
This is my progress so far: http://jsfiddle.net/an5mb2y3/1/

But there are some bugs I could not fix:

- Font smoothing: When I hover over the dropdown menu items, the font gets blurry. After another second, the font gets clear. I read about using -`webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`to fix this, I tried it and had no success.
- Also, the dropdown menu gets displayed in the background, behind the embedded image. I want to show the menu on a top layer of the image. What I tried was changing the `z-index` to a bigger value. But it did not work.
- I want to display the submenu from the position where the parallelogram starts while hovering. I tried `margin-left: 42px;` on the `.submenu` class, but this doesn't work for both dropdown menus at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS dropdown menu up:

```
nav.nav-primary{z-index: 1; position: relative;}
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing one of these bugs. 

But is someone able to explain me why the dropdown menu does get displayed on top, when I disable this: 

.menu > .menu-item {
    /* -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); */
}

Comment: Z-index & position issues